# How to display all of the reviews in my database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display all of the reviews and have incremented them each time so that new reviews can be added but it is only displaying the first review. Here is the part of the code where this is happening from and I have included a modal class called getReview()...Also, after deleting them from firebase, for some reason, my review got inserted again after I just inserted the medical clinic only without the review... I guess the review got save in a caches somewhere?

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // getReference() is the root
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        list.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Information info = snapshot.getValue(Information.class);
            assert info != null;

            String txt = "Medical Clinic: " + info.getName() + " \n\n " + "Review: " + info.getReview() + "\n\nServices Provided: " + info.getDorevitch() + " : " + info.getSkin_Cancer() + " : " + info.getEar_Suctioning();
            list.add(txt);


            //      list.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It is also returning null for some information

Comment: Must I use recycle view instead of listview?

Comment: For some reason, my counter just stops at 3....